# The phrase for when: working in a group to divide responsibility and reduce malicious intent

Tags: meaning, word-usage, terminology

I am trying to think of what the name of the word/phrase is for when:

An important task (not a difficult one, but a mission critical one) is at hand and instead of one person being assigned to it, a group takes on the responsibility to mitigate any consequences happening to one person in case something goes wrong and also to prevent a mistake or malicious intent occurring from one persons doing. (NOT because the task is big and needs to be divided in a group.)

E.g.

> 1. Two different people needing to turn a key each in a device simultaneously to launch a missile.
> 2. Group of people tallying up votes for an election in case one of them were bridged to rig the outcome.

Comment: In addition to Edwin's comprehensive answer, I would mention a phrase that appears in the Wikipedia article he cites (which I have heard in real life): "two-person integrity" (TPI).  While it doesn't use that specific phrase, [this comment](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/114897/apples-open-letter-they-cant-or-wont-backdoor-ios#comment206111_114900 "Apple's open letter – they can't or won't backdoor iOS?") suggests that two trusted Apple employees would need cooperate to handle the security-related aspect of producing the unlocking software that the FBI is asking them to write.

Comment: I would have said distribute responsibility after reading your text, not divide.  Ashworth answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

In the US, and not just for the case where two persons are involved, this is known rather predictably as the **two-man rule**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-man_rule):

> [The examples and perspective in this article deal primarily with the
>   United States and do not represent a worldwide view of the subject.]
>
> The two-man rule is a control mechanism designed to achieve a high
>   level of security for especially critical material or operations.
>   Under this rule all access and actions requires the presence of two
>   authorized people at all times.
>
> *Nuclear weapons*
>
> Per US Air Force Instruction (AFI) 91-104, "The Two-Person Concept" is
>   designed to prevent accidental or malicious launch of nuclear weapons
>   by a single individual....
>
> *No-lone zone*
>
> A no-lone zone is an area that must be staffed by two or more
>   qualified or cleared individuals. Each individual must be within
>   visual contact with each other and in visual contact with the critical
>   component that requires a no-lone-zone area designation. A no-lone
>   zone may contain a cryptographic component, weapon system hardware
>   under test, a nuclear weapon or active nuclear weapon controls....
>
> *Other uses*
>
> The two-man rule is used in other safety critical applications where
>   the presence of two people is required before a potentially hazardous
>   operation can be performed. This is common safety practice in, for
>   example, laboratories and machine shops. In such a context, the
>   additional security may be less important than the fact that if one
>   individual is injured the other can call for help. As another example,
>   firefighters operating in a hazardous environment (i.e. interior
>   structure fire, HAZMAT zone, also known as IDLH, or Immediately
>   Dangerous to Life or Health) function as a team of at least 2 or more
>   personnel. There are commonly more than one team in the same
>   environment, but each team operates as a unit.
>
> Dual keys require the authorization of two separate parties before a
>   particular action is taken. The simplest form of dual key security is
>   a lock that requires two keys to unlock it. The two keys would be in
>   the possession of two separate persons. The lock could only be opened
>   if both parties agreed to open it and at the same time. In 1963,
>   Canada accepted having American W-40 nuclear warheads under dual key
>   control on Canadian soil, to be used on the Canadian BOMARC missiles.
>
> In business, the four-eye principle means that "all business decisions
>   and transactions need approval from the CEO and CFO. Since the CFO is
>   not reporting to the CEO, there is an independent controlling
>   mechanism in place"....
>
> *Civilian aircraft*
>
> In late March 2015 many national aviation authorities and/or airlines
>   made the cockpits of aircraft in flight mandatory "two-man" or
>   "no-lone zones" as a result of the Germanwings Flight 9525
>   crash. Early on in the investigation of that
>   crash, it was believed from the cockpit voice recorder audio, and
>   later supported by flight data recorder information, that the co-pilot
>   deliberately crashed the aircraft after locking the cockpit door when
>   the chief pilot left to use the toilet....